# What is the best way of holding temp data for use in javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, local-storage, information-retrieval

I've been coding for years now, and am not at all new to javascript, or jQuery (I prefer jQuery), and I'm actually pretty good at coding with it. There is, though, one thing I've been thinking about lately that has me scratching my head a little bit, it's something that I've questioned ever since I decided this is the most efficient way I know of doing this, and have been doing this method ever since. But, I always thought there might be a better way of doing it. So, finally, I came to the point where I decided to ask about it here on stackoverflow.

The thing is, when I want to store data values that I want quick access to in a website setting - as I said - I discovered a long time ago - hidden fields definitely come in handy, and even more recently - I discovered instead of using a bunch of hidden fields, I could use just a few - and add "data-(whatever-name-I-decide)" attributes - I can extend one hidden field to hold many pieces of related data. Also, I use cookies too, but I use them for data that needs to be used across pages rather than data that can be used in just one page, so, in such functionality, I'd rather not use cookies, and just hope there's an alternative to my use of hidden fields in these regards.

But, I also am pretty well-versed in c#, and in c# such things can be held in fields (like "... { get; set; }"). Ever since I've used hidden fields in jQuery for these purposes - I've always wondered, and even hoped to have figured out a way to do it more similarly to how this is done with c#, but still till this day, haven't figured an alternative to how I use hidden fields in these regards.

I'm pretty sure there must be an alternative to my approach. In fact, upon coming up with a Title to my question, I stumbled across the page [what is the best way to store data for UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848793/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-data-for-ui) - and it seemed like (I may be wrong, but I doubt I am, but, let's see what someone with better knowledge on the matter has to say) something pointing to a good direction - the comment by Ates Goral to the answer to that question on that page seemed to maybe have some pointers in the right direction in these regards, but, I'm not entirely definite of how to apply what he said - when it comes to an alternative to how I use hidden fields, anyway (because the actual issue that was asked in the question on that page - was slightly similar to this, but not the same...)

Comment: Do you mean setting a global javascript variable?  You can use <script> var myVar = @ViewBag.theVar </script>  at the top of the page.  This will load in some value set in the controller and pass it into a global javascript variable.  This could then be accessed in javascript elsewhere in the page.

Comment: No, I was saying in jQuery script in general, not just in script connected to the controller. Like, plenty of times I use hidden fields in script that has no connection to a controller or c# functionality - like with custom ui that I created that relies on jQuery functionality that I created - for example.

Comment: You don't have to use the ViewBag part, that's just in case you want to load data in from the server.  You could just set var myVar = 8;  Farther down in the js it'll be accessible.

Comment: As a side note, jQuery IS javascript.  it is a specific javascript package.

Comment: I know jQuery is javascript, but, it's the type of javascript I prefer to code in. And, what you said makes sense, and, you put it in terms of a global variable in your original comment (which Ates Goral also mentioned on the link I mentioned in my original question) - and you elaborated in your second comment. Only thing is, I'm not entirely sure about the concept of global variables and how I can use the concept in the way I talked about in my original question (as a replacement to how I use hidden fields). I'm good at making functional scripts, but this is one issue that I never got a grasp

Comment: If you can give me a more detailed explanation of how to use global variables, or a detailed explanation of how I can use your suggestion in general, that would be very helpful. Or maybe a link to a tutorial that explains this concept in a straightforward way, that too would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, instead of putting a piece of info as an attribute on a hidden field, like data-userFirstName="Pete" you just do var userFirstName = "Pete".  Then, instead of using jQuery to go get the name, you already have it.  if var userLastName = "Smith" you could then do console.log(userFirstName + ' ' + userLastName);

Comment: What is difficult about your question is that it is too broad.  Give me a specific example with some html using a hidden field and what you want to do with it, and I'll convert it to a global var for you.

Comment: I think Richard's answer might be what I'm looking for. But thanks for trying to help me too. And, in response to you asking a more specific example - what I use hidden fields for in the way I was asking about in the question is - let's say I have a function, it does something. But then, with user interaction, another function is triggered that deals with the same html elements that the original function dealt with - but the other function requires some data to properly do what is required, and so, the original function inserted this required data into a hidden field so that the other function

Comment: (continued...) ...will have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you reference, the answer discusses javascript objects. If that's what you're looking for, you can make one like this:

```
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyeColor:"blue"
};
```

To get a value:

```
var fname = person.firstName;
```

To set a value:

```
person.firstName = "Tom";
```

Comment: hmmm, this sounds very promising, I will experiment with it, and I think you probably answered my question here. Once I experiment with it, I will come back and mark your answer as the answer to my question, or if I have further questions, I will ask away. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds good!  I tend to use global variables in my pages, and having one object or array (depending on the specific need) to store/group them is a pretty tidy method.

Comment: How are the js objects coming along @AspCoder?  Any questions so far?

Comment: Im working on adding a feature to my code right now which resulted in some buggy behaviour, once I ironed that out and have implemented the feature I'm working on I'm going to experiment with and implement what you've shown me here. I'll be back with a comment here when I'm doing that. Thanks a lot again.